# Annonces SNCF: qualité du français

Tags: prononciation

Même si je ne suis pas d'origine française, j'ai passé pas mal de temps dans les gares SNCF, et donc j'ai pu entendre maintes annonces (toutes enregistrées par une certaine Simone Hérault).

Selon vous, dont la première langue est le français, est-ce que sa prononciation est d'une clarté et précision exceptionnelles ? Est-elle la voix française par excellence ?

Comment: Chaque mot est correct, mais les phrases sont un peu lentes et n'ont pas vraiment de rhythme car elles sont construites par morceaux.

Comment: Infos : [SNCF](http://www.sncf.com/fr/identite/simone-voix-sncf) (voir vidéo).

Answer (score 10):

Il n'y a pas de modèle, d'excellence, chaque voix est singulière.

Son articulation est optimale, elle doit être entendue dans un milieu bruyant et sa prononciation ne révèle aucun accent particulier.

La voix est bien placée (ni dans la gorge, ni dans le nez, ni dans les aigus ou les graves,...) bref elle 'passe' bien.

On peut lui reprocher de très légères intonations formatées "hôtesse d'accueil" (façon de ralentir, ou d'insister sur certaines syllabes), mais elles sont induites par son rôle d'informatrice des clients de la SNCF.

C'est un bon exemple pour s'entraîner à une diction pour un exposé ou une conférence.

Comment: Merci. Dorénavant je m'entraînerai en répétant pendant des heures ses formules ... égarez-vous du bordure du quai ... Luçon, La Rochelle, Rochefort ... numéro deux mille huit cent vingt ... en provenance de ... à destination ... Le Mans, ici, Le Mans ...

Comment: @Hautfrançais « Éloignez-vous de la bordure du quai »

Comment: @Hautfrançais c'est un excellent exercice d'acteur (théâtre), à faire en gardant la diction impeccable et ralentie et en traduisant l'impatience, l'énervement, le soulagement, l'autorité, la rêverie .... en plus, vous citez des villes du bord de mer où il fait bon vivre... et n'oubliez pas le notes du signal sonore précédent l'annonce.